# Rational DOORS DXL: can I check for existence of a local string variable?

Tags: ibm-doors

Suppose I have a DXL macro with various if/else sections such that a particular string is created only under certain conditions and not other times.  How can I test for existence before trying to use said string?  I'm looking for the equivalent of

```
if (exist string foo) {
     do_something
    } else {
     do_some_other_thing
}
```

I could kludge a workaround by initialising `string foo = "notset"` and testing to see if the value was changed, but would prefer something that doesn't require creating the string variable if not needed.

Note that this is a local string, not something found (or not found) in an attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that DXL has scoping. Code like this won't work:

```
if (cond) {
   string s = "Hello";
} else {
   // something different
}
if (s == ...) print "..." // parse time error, s not defined
```

You need to use something like this:

```
string s = null; 
if (cond1) {
    s = "Hallo"; 
} else {
    // something different
}
if (!null s) print "...";
```

I hope you were not talking about checking if inside the DXL code a variable is declared. This is not possible, since a non declared variable will yield a parse time error before any DXL is executed (autodeclare turned off). And you should never rely on autodeclare.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `if (null string_variable) {`? If the string is declared but not given a value, this will evaluate to `true`, so it may not be exactly what you want. It may also give you an execution error if the string hasn't been declared yet.